# Getting the User's Latitude & Longitude in Python

Tags: python, location, latitude-longitude

I want to obtain the users location in python. I assume this is somehow possible because google is able to do it (https://maps.google.com/ hit the circle below the D-Pad).

Does anyone know how?

Comment: html5 provides some js function that lets you get user location ... but it is a pain to interface from python in my experience ... theres lots of api's online to look up a users location based on IP ... just keep in mind it wont be very exact

Comment: are you running python on the client or the server?  If client, what sort of client (e.g. Windows, Mac, Mobile?)

Comment: In general, whether your answer is "a web server", "a Windows desktop app", etc., your first step should probably be to [search PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=location). There are dozens of modules for IP-based geolocation, accessing OS X's CoreLocation APIs, and everything else you can imagine. StackOverflow is not a good place to get recommendations for modules, but it's a great place to get help if you start using one and get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll you own, there are web sites that will give information about your IP address in various formats.

http://ipinfo.io/json will give something like this:

```
{
  "ip": "12.34.56.78",
  "hostname": "XXXXX.com",
  "city": "Saint-Lambert",
  "region": "Quebec",
  "country": "CA",
  "loc": "45.5073,-73.5082",
  "org": "AS577 Bell Canada",
  "postal": "J4P"
}
```

Like Joran said above, this won't be exact. I'm not in Saint-Lambert, I'm in Montreal, but it isn't that far.

You can grab that in Python with urllib2.urlopen, then turn it into a dict with the json module.

```
import json
import urllib2

def location_lookup():
  try:
    return json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://ipinfo.io/json'))
  except urllib2.HTTPError:
    return False

location = location_lookup()

# print city and latitude/longitude
print location['city'] + ' (' + location['loc'] + ')'
```

For the JSON output above, this Python code will give

```
Saint-Lambert (45.5073,-73.5082)
```